# How to unit test plotly click event with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, plotly

Need to cover the code which is executed on plotly click event i.e onEventPieClicked()

Unit test case:

```
it('should call onEventPieClicked function with plotly click event', function() {
    spyOn(window, 'onEventPieClicked');
    $('#pieChartbyMachibeType').trigger('plotly_click');
    expect(window.onEventPieClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Controller Code:

```
$('#pieChartbyMachibeType').on('plotly_click', function (data) {
    onEventPieClicked(data);
});
```

It has to call onEventPieClicked() function but it's never called.